# chroot: Ubuntu 14.04 - udev upgrade Problems!

Tags: apt, upgrade, dpkg, udev

im running Ubuntu 14.04 (x86) on a OpenELEC (x64) host system.
Everything worked great until a few days ago when it tried to upgrade the "udev" package after running apt-get upgrade.

```
apt-get upgrade output:
Setting up udev (204-5ubuntu20.5) ...
runlevel:/var/run/utmp: No such file or directory
 * udev requires hotplug support, not started
   ...fail!
invoke-rc.d: initscript udev, action "restart" failed.
dpkg: error processing package udev (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 udev
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

The System still runs fine and i can install other packages but i would still like to get rid of this error. Any Ideas?

Comment: chroot is to a large extent depreciated in favor of LXC . I am not sure how to resolve your error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/var/run/utmp` seems to be missing possibly due to improper shutdown. Try to re-create it using:

```
sudo -s
cat /dev/null > /var/run/utmp
```

and then restart your computer.

Comment: Thanks this worked fine... is there a special way to do a chroot shutdown? never bothered to do this.

Comment: `reboot` or `shutdown -r 0`