# 14.04 Error with install CURL

Tags: 14.04

I install Ubuntu 14.04,
When i add:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

I get this error:

```
root@:~# sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up udev (204-5ubuntu20.8) ...
* udev requires hotplug support, not started
...fail!
invoke-rc.d: initscript udev, action "restart" failed.
dpkg: error processing package udev (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
udev
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
root@:~#
```

When i add:

```
sudo apt-get install curl
```

I get this error:

```
Setting up udev (204-5ubuntu20.8) ...
* udev requires hotplug support, not started
...fail!
invoke-rc.d: initscript udev, action "restart" failed.
dpkg: error processing package udev (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
udev
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
root@:~#
```

Anyone know how to fix this ?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [chroot: Ubuntu 14.04 - udev upgrade Problems!](http://askubuntu.com/questions/520550/chroot-ubuntu-14-04-udev-upgrade-problems)

Comment: @CharlesGreen this not work for me, i add this command:

sudo -s
cat /dev/null > /var/run/utmp

And again is same error, any solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [lengthy post](http://forum.ovh.co.uk/showthread.php?8480-udev-requires-hotplug-support-not-started/page2&s=6f128c7420b4e4f8984574a24c37c807) with an 'ugly fix' for this problem:  I do not know what else this would break.

From a terminal window, edit `/etc/init.d/udev` as follows:

`sudo nano /etc/init.d/udev`

After the ### END INIT INFO add:

exit 0

Save and exit.

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: Your problem there is that you are on Ubuntu 13.10, and the software has moved.  Your archives will need to be updated, as detailed in http://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release

Comment: no, i install 14.04 LTS and again have this error: E: Unable to locate package ubuntu-restricted-extras

Comment: It should be in the multiverse - there is not space enough here to add pictures and stuff.  Can you ask that as a new question?

Comment: Unfortunately the question is closed - you can edit it to reflect the change to 14.04, and flag it for reopening...